# String to local date error

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am trying to convert from string to localdate(JODA TIME) but its giving me error

```
String theDate = w.getPSDate();  == 6/03/2013
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(theDate);
System.out.println(ld);
```

for some reason, I have to use string instead of date. I want to print the date as (06/03/2013). what is the error in the code?

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "06/03/2013" is malformed at "/03/2013"
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:747)
at org.joda.time.convert.StringConverter.getPartialValues(StringConverter.java:87)
at org.joda.time.LocalDate.<init>(LocalDate.java:406)
at org.joda.time.LocalDate.<init>(LocalDate.java:354)
at Date.GetDate.main(GetDate.java:94)
```

Java Result: 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead:

```
// Are you sure it's 6/03/2013 rather than 06/03/2013? dd would be nicer...
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate date = formatter.parseLocalDate(text);
```

Comment: if i print the date it comes out as 2013-03-06, instead of 06/03/2013. it is 06/03/2013.

Comment: @vijay: Your question asked about converting *from* `String` *to* `LocalDate`. To convert in the other direction, you can use the same formatter with its `print` method.